# Incorrect Syntax error with If statements

Tags: sql, syntax

I am trying to create an If statement that will find and list the following values if the item is over 100K or the company is named CGELENA or CGFEDUN and if not then check to see if the commodity type is listed below

```
If (ord_miscqty >='100000' OR m.cmp_id in('CGELENA','CGFEDUN')
    Begin
    Select 
    ord_number
        ,ord_status
        ,m.cmp_name
        ,Ord_startdate
        ,ord_miscqty AS [FreightValue]
        ,c.car_ins_cargolimits AS [CargoAmount]
        ,o.ord_carrier AS [Carrier]
        ,l.NAME AS [LSM2]
        ,c.car_iccnum AS [MCNumber]
        ,o.ord_description AS [Commodity]
        ,f.cmd_code [Commody Code]
        ,(
            SELECT t.ta_quantity
            FROM trlaccessories AS t
            WHERE o.ord_carrier = t.ta_trailer
                AND t.ta_type = 'POWER'
            ) AS [PowerUnits]
        ,(
            SELECT n.not_text
            FROM notes AS n
            WHERE n.nre_tablekey = o.ord_carrier
                AND n.not_type = 'I'
            ) AS [Note]
        ,(
            SELECT n.last_updatedatetime
            FROM notes AS n
            WHERE n.nre_tablekey = o.ord_carrier
                AND n.not_type = 'I'
            ) AS [NoteDate]
        ,(
            SELECT q.caq_type
            FROM carrierqualifications AS q
            WHERE o.ord_carrier = q.caq_id
                AND q.caq_type = 'RES'
            ) AS [Restriction]
        ,(
            SELECT n.not_expires
            FROM notes AS n
            WHERE n.nre_tablekey = o.ord_carrier
                AND n.not_type = 'I'
            ) AS [NoteExp]
    FROM orderheader AS o
    INNER JOIN carrier AS c ON o.ord_carrier = c.car_id
    INNER JOIN company AS m ON o.ord_billto = m.cmp_id
    INNER JOIN labelfile AS l ON o.ord_revtype3 = l.abbr
    join stops as s on s.ord_hdrnumber = o.ord_hdrnumber
    join FREIGHTDETAIL as f on f.stp_number = s.stp_number
    Where datediff(hour, getdate(), ord_startdate) > 0
        AND ord_status IN (
            'PLN'
            ,'DSP'
            )
        AND l.labeldefinition = 'RevType3'
    End 

    Else If
    f.cmd_code in ('COPSUL',
    'HAZMOLY',
    'COPANO',
    'COPCAN',
    'COPING',
    'COPPAN',
    'COPPER',
    'COPROD',
    'COPSTSHT',
    'COPSULNH',
    'APPLINCS',
    'LIQUOR') 
    Begin
    Select 
    ord_number
        ,ord_status
        ,m.cmp_name
        ,Ord_startdate
        ,ord_miscqty AS [FreightValue]
        ,c.car_ins_cargolimits AS [CargoAmount]
        ,o.ord_carrier AS [Carrier]
        ,l.NAME AS [LSM2]
        ,c.car_iccnum AS [MCNumber]
        ,o.ord_description AS [Commodity]
        ,f.cmd_code [Commody Code]
        ,(
            SELECT t.ta_quantity
            FROM trlaccessories AS t
            WHERE o.ord_carrier = t.ta_trailer
                AND t.ta_type = 'POWER'
            ) AS [PowerUnits]
        ,(
            SELECT n.not_text
            FROM notes AS n
            WHERE n.nre_tablekey = o.ord_carrier
                AND n.not_type = 'I'
            ) AS [Note]
        ,(
            SELECT n.last_updatedatetime
            FROM notes AS n
            WHERE n.nre_tablekey = o.ord_carrier
                AND n.not_type = 'I'
            ) AS [NoteDate]
        ,(
            SELECT q.caq_type
            FROM carrierqualifications AS q
            WHERE o.ord_carrier = q.caq_id
                AND q.caq_type = 'RES'
            ) AS [Restriction]
        ,(
            SELECT n.not_expires
            FROM notes AS n
            WHERE n.nre_tablekey = o.ord_carrier
                AND n.not_type = 'I'
            ) AS [NoteExp]
    FROM orderheader AS o
    INNER JOIN carrier AS c ON o.ord_carrier = c.car_id
    INNER JOIN company AS m ON o.ord_billto = m.cmp_id
    INNER JOIN labelfile AS l ON o.ord_revtype3 = l.abbr
    join stops as s on s.ord_hdrnumber = o.ord_hdrnumber
    join FREIGHTDETAIL as f on f.stp_number = s.stp_number
    Where datediff(hour, getdate(), ord_startdate) > 0
        AND ord_status IN (
            'PLN'
            ,'DSP'
            )
        AND l.labeldefinition = 'RevType3'
    End
```

Comment: Missing `)` on line 1 for a start

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? Some of them may not support `IF/ELSE` control structures in context of a regular query, instead only allowing them in stored procedures/functions. The `[]` brackets suggest probably MS SQL Server or Access.

Comment: O my God, you wrote such a monster and can not find missing bracket??

Answer (score 0):

In the else statement you have to use a **SELECT**

```
Else If
Select f.cmd_code in ('COPSUL',...
....
```